# How to filter a constexpr `std::array` with a `UnaryPredicate` lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

Given a `constexpr std::array` and an `UnaryPredicate pred`, how can I filter the array to return a new `constexpr std::array` which all of its elements meets `pred(e)`?

```
struct foo {
    int f1;
    int f2;
};
static constexpr std::array<foo, 5> arr{ foo{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}, {4,4}, {5,5} };

int main() {
    // will result in { foo{1,1}, {2,2}, {4,4}, {5,5} }
    constexpr auto filterd = filter_array(arr, [](const foo& f) {return f.f1 != 3;})
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you using c++20? since lot of   algorithm such as `std::remove_if` are `constexpr` right now.

Comment: But the `arr` is constant, it can't be modified, but rather to generate a new array. I tried the `remove_if` and the compiler complains ` you cannot assign to a variable that is const`

Comment: No, we can copy `arr` inside the lambda and modify it, then using  `constexpr std::pair` to accept it modified `arr` and correspond size, but gcc-10 current has some [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96575) with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's definitely that, **dependent type**, the type that depends on a **value**, is impossible in present-day C++. you can't decide the size `M` of result type `std::array<T, M>` by only the function arguments, which means `M` must be a template argument.

so you have to provide an additional template argument `M` for the result type, by a `constexpr` function `count_if`, and then just decide each element to be which value:

```cpp
template<size_t I, typename T, typename Pred, std::enable_if_t<I == 0, int> = 0>
constexpr T get_element_helper(T const* arr, Pred&& pred){
    return pred(arr[0]) ? arr[0] : get_element_helper<0>(arr + 1, pred);
}
template<size_t I, typename T, typename Pred, std::enable_if_t<I != 0, int> = 0>
constexpr T get_element_helper(T const* arr, Pred&& pred){
    return pred(arr[0]) ? get_element_helper<I - 1>(arr + 1, pred) : get_element_helper<I>(arr + 1, pred);
}

template<typename T, size_t N, typename Pred, size_t ...Is>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> filter_array_helper(std::array<T, N> const& arr, Pred&& pred, std::index_sequence<Is...>*){
    return { get_element_helper<Is>(arr.data(), pred)... };
}
template<size_t M, typename T, size_t N, typename Pred>
constexpr std::array<T, M> filter_array(std::array<T, N> const& arr, Pred&& pred){
    return filter_array_helper(arr, std::forward<Pred>(pred), (std::make_index_sequence<M>*)nullptr);
}

template<typename T, size_t N, typename Pred, size_t... Is>
constexpr size_t count_if_helper(std::array<T, N> const& arr, Pred&& pred, std::index_sequence<Is...>*){
    return ((size_t)(bool)pred(arr[Is]) + ...);
}
template<typename T, size_t N, typename Pred>
constexpr size_t count_if(std::array<T, N> const& arr, Pred&& pred){
    return count_if_helper(arr, std::forward<Pred>(pred), (std::make_index_sequence<N>*)nullptr);
};



int main(){
    constexpr std::array<int, 5> a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    constexpr auto pred = [](int a){ return a % 2 == 0; };
    constexpr auto b = filter_array<count_if(a, pred)>(a, pred); // std::array<int, 3>{0, 2, 4}
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `get_element_helper` is what I am missing, very smart! BTW, c++17 allows local var and for loop been used in a constexpr function, `count_if` can actually be implemented in a single function.

Comment: @zoujyjs you're right. it's that I have been used to it. anyway, thanks to C++17!

Answer (score 1):

Since a lot of algorithm in `<algorithm>` is `constexpr` in C++20, we can just use it in meta-programming in a natural way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>    

struct foo {
  int f1;
  int f2;
  bool operator==(const foo&) const = default;
};

constexpr static std::array arr{foo{1,1}, foo{2,2}, foo{3,3}, foo{4,4}, foo{5,5}};

constexpr auto filter_array(auto pred) {
  constexpr auto p = [=] {
    auto res = arr;
    auto size = std::distance(res.begin(), std::remove_if(res.begin(), res.end(), pred));
    return std::pair{res, size};
  }();
  constexpr auto res = p.first;
  constexpr auto size = p.second;
  return [=]<auto... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array{res[Is]...};
  }(std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
}

int main() {
  // will result in { foo{1,1}, {2,2}, {4,4}, {5,5} }
  constexpr auto filterd = filter_array([](const foo& f) { return f.f1 == 3; });
  static_assert(filterd == std::array{foo{1,1}, foo{2,2}, foo{4,4}, foo{5,5}});
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/Yhz6eP)

Comment: Yeah the assembly code does compiled to the desired result. It's a bit radical to use it in my situation, where it does not even compile in latest msvc 2019. Anyway this is helpful for using the state of art standards.